# Alter table in Oracle 10G - virtual column

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am new with Oracle DB. When I execute in Oracle database version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_1 
ADD (CD1 AS ( CAST(MYDATE - 1 AS TIMESTAMP(6)) ) VIRTUAL NOT NULL);
```

I get successful output:
table TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_1 altered.

But when I execute the same code in version: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production I get an error:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_1 
ADD (CD1 AS ( CAST(MYDATE - 1 AS TIMESTAMP(6)) ) VIRTUAL NOT NULL)
Error SQL: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
```

Any ideas why I am getting this output? Any workaround for this code?

EDIT:

The code I have is the following:

```
create table TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_1 compress as select * from myTable partition(P20141023);

ALTER TABLE TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_1 
ADD (MYDATE AS ( CAST(CREATION_DATE - 1 AS TIMESTAMP(6)) ) VIRTUAL NOT NULL);
create table TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_2 compress as 
select COLUMN1,COLUMN2,MYDATE AS CREATION_DATE,COLUMN3
from TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_1;
;
ALTER TABLE myTable EXCHANGE PARTITION P20141022 WITH TABLE TEMP_WORKING_TABLE_2 INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

I am trying to exchange partitions. I was using virtual column in Oracle 11G.

Comment: Create a view in 10g.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual columns were a [new feature of 11gR1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO07254), they do not exist in 10g.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish with a virtual column, some potential workarounds are creating a view, a materialized view, or a function based index.